# git svn as a crutch for svn merging woes

Tags: git-svn

Consider an svn repository that has branches that are not necessarily located in the usual trunk/tags/branches layout. I want to persuade git-svn to take two of those branches on board, plus whatever else it needs, so that I can use git as a merge tool to avoid various levels of heck that have been plaguing us with svn merging. If the branches are all in one place, there's `--branches`, but is there a way if they are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your `git svn init ROOT_URL`, then go in and edit your `.git/config` to add additional `fetch`lines:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
   url = https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/mpi
   fetch = mpich2/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
   fetch = mpich2/branches/dev/threads:refs/remotes/threads
   fetch = mpich2/branches/dev/knem:refs/remotes/knem
   fetch = mpich2/branches/release/MPICH2_1_0_8:refs/remotes/mpich2-1.0.8
```

Then `git fetch` and you should get all of the branches explicitly listed in your config file.

Be aware, however, that you may not want to actually pursue merging externally via `git-svn`.  Git won't maintain the `svn:mergeinfo` properties for you, which will make going back to a native SVN-based merge workflow nearly impossible.  You might also confuse `git-svn` quite a bit by cherry-picking or merging code that has already been committed to the actual SVN repo, since it searches for `git-svn-id:` "breadcrumbs" in the commit messages in order to figure out which SVN path should be used for `git svn dcommit`.  See the `CAVEATS` section of the git-svn man page for additional info about this.

FWIW, I've also [posted about this in longer form on my own site](http://davegoodell.blogspot.com/2009/04/multiple-remote-branches-in-git-svn.html).